# Random walk where each step depends on parity

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $(S_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a random walk on the integers with transition probabilities
$$p_{i, i-1} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
p, & \text{if $i$ is even} \\ 
1 - p & \text{if $i$ is odd},
\end{matrix}\right. \ \ \ \ p_{i,i+1} = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1-p, & \text{if $i$ is even} \\ 
p & \text{if $i$ is odd},
\end{matrix}\right. \ \ \ \ 0 < p < \frac{1}{2}.$$
I want to find out if this random walk is recurrent or transient. There are a couple ways to show recurrence of random walk that I know of:

1. Show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(S_{2n}= 0) = \infty$
2. Show that $P(T< \infty) = 1$ where $T$ is some hitting time
3. Exhibit a stationary distribution

However, I do not know which one to use here, or which one would be the easiest. How does one do this problem? And, if you don't mind, can you explain how one could look at a problem like this and know which "method" to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the steps in pairs. The resulting random walk on the sites of a given parity remains in place with probability $p^2+(1-p)^2$ and goes in either direction with equal probability $p(1-p)$. Since the symmetric random walk is known to be recurrent, this one is as well; the probability to remain in place just slows things down.

I’m afraid I don’t know (or at least don’t have reflective access to any knowledge I have about) how one looks at a problem like this and knows which method to use – I think it’s mostly experience.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "combine the steps in pairs" what do you mean?

Comment: @MathIsLife12: I mean: Consider $R_k:=S_{2k}$. This is a random walk that stays on the integers of a given parity (the parity of $S_0$) and has the transition probabilities described. If it is recurrent, it follows that $S$ is recurrent.

Comment: If I have that $S_0 = 0$ and I just consider the random walk on the even integers, then the upstep probability is $1-p$ and the downstep probability is $p$, right?

Comment: @MathIsLife12: No. You go in one direction with probability $p$ in the first step and then continue in that direction with probability $1-p$ in the second step. You go in the other direction with probability $1-p$ in the first step and then continue in that direction with probability $p$ in the second step. In either case, the probability that you end up on either side is $p(1-p)$, and the remaining probability $1-2p(1-p)=p^2+(1-p)^2$ is the probability to remain in place.